# How can I get out of a bad state in `iex`?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

When using `iex`, I sometimes create an incomplete expression by accident. A trivial example:

```
iex(1) String.reverse("foo"
...(1)
```

If I supplied the missing `)` here, all would be well, but sometimes I don't see what I did wrong.

Is there a way to abandon the current expression - to say, "actually, forget that, just put me back on a working prompt?" `Control + C` doesn't solve it; my options are to `(a)bort` and kill the shell entirely, or `(c)ontinue` and try to figure it out myself.

By contrast, Ruby's `irb` will just forget the incomplete expression if I press `Control + C`.

How can I recover from a mistake in the Elixir shell?

Comment: Hmm. I hadn't seen the one that this duplicates. Oh well - I worded this question as many ways as I could to make it searchable, so hopefully other people can use this as a way to find the original. :)